# Can I cast Death Ward on additional creatures without causing previous castings to end?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Say I have cast Death Ward on one creature already. Can I cast Death Ward again on an additional creature without causing the first casting of Death Ward to end?

Answer (score 31):

### Casting Death Ward will not end prior castings

The [*death ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/death-ward) spell does not require concentration and it states:

> You touch a creature and grant it a measure of protection from death. The first time the target would drop to 0 hit points as a result of taking damage, the target instead drops to 1 hit point, and the spell ends. If the spell is still in effect when the target is subjected to an effect that would kill it instantaneously without dealing damage, that effect is instead negated against the target, and the spell ends.

Note that the description never says only one creature can be under the effects at a time, or that the spell ends if you cast it on another creature. Thus the spell does not end if you cast it again on another creature.

An example of a spell that does do this is the [*light*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/light) spell which states:

> [...] The spell ends if you cast it again or dismiss it as an action [...]

Comment: Perfectly answer : the Light spell example prove that some spells without concentration still can restrict having multiple instance active simultaneously and that Death Ward isn't one of them.

Comment: You would however have to be an 8th level Cleric to have enough 4th level spell slots to cast it twice between long rests. A 20th level could theoretically cast it 12 times in a day, by burning their higher-level slots.

Comment: @T.E.D. alternatively be a Sorcerer multi-class and use flexible casting, or use a ring of spell storing.

Comment: @MooingDuck yes it does. "If the spell is still in effect when the target is subjected to an effect that would **kill it instantaneously without dealing damage**, that effect is instead negated against the target, and the spell ends." *Power Word: Kill* is one such effect

Comment: @Medix2: Oops, I saw "would drop to 0 hit points" and stopped reading. My bad.